# Django ManyToMany two for loops

Tags: django, django-templates, django-haystack

I have two for loops from which the first one (for i in var) is for getting the posts and the other is for getting the  tags (ManyToManyField in the Post model) for that post:

```
{% for i in var %}
    {% for j in i.tags.all %}
        {{ j.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Why won't this work?

EDIT:

Here is what the variables contain:

var:

```
[<SearchResult: myapp.post (pk='1')>, <SearchResult: myapp.post (pk='2')>]
```

and here is {{ i.tags }}:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1620dd0>
```

If I try to iterate it with .all it returns nothing.

EDIT 2:

This might be the problem - var is a variable from a SearchQuerySet (django haystack):

```
var = SearchQuerySet().all()
```

Comment: Do each of the variables contain what you think it contains?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What type of variable is `var`, and when you iterate over it, what is `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the template, the `j` is something like `<SearchResult: myapp.post (pk='1')>`, which does not have `.tags` attributes. Try `for j in i.object.tags.all`, the [`.object`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchresult_api.html#attribute-reference) refers the actual Model instance.

Note that Django normally does not complain about trying of accessing non-existing attributes (`i.tags` here) during template rendering. Hence rendering nothing may also mean incorrect attributes referring.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the tag field into the haystack searchindex. Now it outputs the list of tags. Thank you all for your help!